# A better replacement for istrstream?

Tags: c++, stringstream, c++17, string-view

`istrstream` was perfect for my needs - basically, take a fixed char buffer, and give me a simple way to extract lines `getline()` and test for `eof()`

I'm switching our projects to C++ 17 compliance - which has deprecated `istrsteam` - apparently because there are too many C++ programmers who cannot fathom fixed buffer memory management (are you serious?!)

At any rate, the `istringstream` provides the same use semantics, but it imposes the need to now copy the entire fixed character buffer at construction time.

This is an anti-pattern.

What I am looking for is either a way to use a `string_view` in place of a `string` for the `istringstream`, or alternately a better replacement for `stringstream` which itself handles externally managed fixed buffer (it need only point into it, it never need worry about managing that resource, just as `strstream` did).

Currently, in VS 2017, this is illegal, and if I understand things correctly, is illegal everywhere in the current state-of-art of C++ (I'm sure you'll correct me if I'm wrong!)

```
    std::string_view raw_view(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(raw_buffer.get()), raw_buffer.size());
    std::istringstream raw_stream(raw_view);
```

**So - ideas?**

Note: Peter Sommerlad has a proposal for this exact idea here for the C++ standards body:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0448r1.pdf

Comment: `istrstream` has been deprecated since C++98...

Comment: sure - and I've been waiting for a string_view since then as well... which they finally got off their butts long enough to do for '17, only to fail to actually use it in any of the most obvious library interfaces...

Comment: Nobody's been stopping you from imparting your apparently infinite wisdom upon the committee and writing proposals for these things.

Comment: Shouldn't `getline()` on a fixed buffer itself return a substring as a `string_view`?  It's trivial to create a new independent string if you need one, but impossible to undo a copy done inside the library.

Comment: In any case, building atop iostreams is not what you want if efficiency is a concern.

Comment: Ben - that would change the interface - would need a getline_view() or similar, to return a view.  The linked proposal above operates using spans, rather than views, but the idea is to never generate an allocation, just views within views.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continue using `istrstream` for the time being. It likely won't be removed until either [P0448](http://wg21.link/P0448) (using `std::span<char>` as the source/destination of a stream buffer) or [P0408](http://wg21.link/P0408) (the ability to move data into/outof `stringstream`s) is adopted by the standard. Either of those would serve your needs well.

That being said, if all you're trying to do is get substrings between `\n`s, it would be far more efficient (even with the above proposals) to just use a regex search. Or just a *regular* search, since you're just looking for `\n`. That would give you a pair of iterators that represents a line. Using iostreams for line-by-line processing of an already-loaded character buffer is overkill and will never be as efficient as the alternative.

Comment: A few lines of code to illustrate what you are talking about would be very useful for not-as-experienced C++ developers, IMHO

Comment: I use `istrstream` in a couple of places - one could trivially be converted as you say to simply look for the next EOL or EOS.  The other uses more stream features, including locale injection, so wouldn't be so trivial and although those could be rewritten too - would be considerably more involved.  Thanks for the feedback & answer.